# Intuition and conditional probability, Bayesian

Tags: distributions, bayesian, inference, conditional-probability

There are two students, who have come for admission in a school. Both the students submitted their respective latest test scores (from their previous schools). One student had appeared in an easy test, and the other had appeared in a difficult test. Both however, have received the exact same scores (out of hundred).

The school wants to admit the student who has worked the hardest.

Assume that the probability of each working harder than the other is $0.5$ each, when both the test scores and the difficulties of the tests are unknown.

Assuming that working harder increases the expected scores, and that increasing difficulty reduces the expected scores (equivalently, increasing ease increases expected test score), what is the probability that the student who appeared for the easier test has worked harder (not the exact probability, just whether it is greater than or less than $0.5$)?

**Common sense**

From a common sense perspective, it appears that the probability would be less than $0.5$, because he has appeared for an easier test and still scored the same. But common sense, may not always work when it comes to probabilities. So I tried to dig deeper.

**How I approached the problem**

Let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be the efforts put in by two students, $r_1, r_2$ the ease of the tests respectively (lesser is r, more difficult is the test) and $m_1, m_2$ the test scores respectively.

I want to find

$P(e_1 > e_2 | r_1 > r_2, m_1 = m_2)$

With some algebra, and assuming $r_1, r_2, e_1, e_2$ are identically and independently distributed prior to the score and difficulty information, I turn it into this,

$ \frac{P(m_1 = m_2 | r_1 > r_2, e_1 >e_2) P (e_1 > e_2)} {P(m_1=m_2 | r_1>r_2)} $

Because the prior probability, $P(e_1>e_2) = 0.5$, the overall expression will be less than $0.5$ if and only if

$P(m_1 = m_2 | r_1 > r_2, e_1 >e_2) < P(m_1=m_2 | r_1>r_2)$.

Again, from a common sense perspective, because the expected score increases with hard work and also with ease, it appears that the condition would be met.

But is it actually mathematically guaranteed to be so? If yes, how to prove that? If not, what can be an example of a probability distribution for test scores, perhaps as a function of difficulty and hard work, that would lead to the violation of the condition, and thus leading to the conclusion that there is more than 50% chance that the student who appeared for the easier test actually worked harder?

**Alternate models**

Or am I modeling the situation in an improper way altogether? Would some other model be better?

Comment: Please **do not** delete your question and re-post it again. In such cases the new questions would be closed as duplicates of the old ones. In long run, this could lead to getting you automatically suspended by the site algorithms.